# Problema con ortools

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código (parte de él)

```
dimension = 5
plants  = range(dimension)
customers = range(dimension)
cost  = [[[random.randint(1,100) for i in plants] for j in customers]] #randomly costs of meeting costumer demands
fcost = [[random.randint(1,100) for i in plants]] #randomly cost of opening (or keep open) production plants
#cost anf fcost arrays are a vector of vectors

solver = pywraplp.Solver('UncapacitatedFacilityLocationProblem', pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING) #we use this one because it is free


x = { (i,j) : solver.BoolVar('x[%i, %i]' % (i, j)) for i in plants for j in customers} #Boolean variable is a variable which values are 0 or 1
y = { i : solver.BoolVar('y[%i]' % (i)) for i in plants }
#Remember that %i is to show integer value

solver.Minimize(solver.Sum(fcost[i] * y[i] for i in plants) + solver.Sum(cost[i][j] * x[i,j] for i in plants for j in customers))
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2ed7de854246> in <module>()
---> 29 solver.Minimize(solver.Sum(fcost[i] * y[i] for i in plants) + solver.Sum(cost[i][j] * x[i,j] for i in plants for j in customers))
```

¿Alguna idea de qué puede ser y cómo solucionarlo?
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser porque pusiste brackets extra en cost y fcost, probablemente buscas algo como:

```
cost  = [[random.randint(1, 100) for i in plants] for j in customers]
fcost = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in plants]
```

Hazle print a ambas listas para que veas la diferencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ese era el fallo